# Rules "After a new content is saved" interferring with hook_node_insert?

Tags: 7, rules, nodes

I have a Rules triggering after new content is saved, *and* in a custom module a hook_node_insert function.

It seems that when one is activated the other one is disactivated... Is it normal behaviour ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try hooking on [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) ?

Comment: Thx, I guess I will. But is it normal anyway ?